# User Truffle on Testrpc offline

Tags: truffle, testrpc

How can I get truffle to compile contracts over my local testrpc setup without an internet connection for test purposes.

I do not have the privilege of internet access at home, but I prefer working at home. When deploying a contract via truffle with internet connection everything works fine.

Running "truffle deploy" without internet connection gives me the following error.

```
>Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum clien                                        
 t:
     - is running
     - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
     - is accessible over the network
     - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)
```

So I run "testrpc" then on a separate console I navigate to my project folder and run "truffle depoly". This works with internet connection, but gives error, when not connected to an internet connection.

truffle.js

```
> module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

How can I deploy contracts without internet connection on my local testrpc?

Update on System information:

```
OS: Windows 7 Profession Service Pack 1
Truffle v4.0.0 (core: 4.0.0)
Solidity v0.4.18 (solc-js)
```

Comment: I've tried your setup without internet and it worked. Launch `testrpc` in a console "EthereumJS TestRPC v4.1.3", and execute `truffle migrate` in another console "Truffle v3.4.11 (core: 3.4.11)". Everything under Ubuntu 16.04 x64. The project used as a test was the default created by `truffle init`.  Make sure testrpc is running before executing `truffle migrate` or (`deploy` is an alias of `migrate`). Which OS are you running?

Comment: I am using windows 7. Using `Truffle v3.4.11 (core: 3.4.11)
Solidity v0.4.15 (solc-js)`. Actually testing using the `pet-shop-tutorial` tutorial, [http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone, who may experience similar issue. Here's a quick solution I found to get truffle v4 working offline.

So `truffle deploy` doesn't work offline (specifically without connected to a wifi/LAN connection) because of truffle's need to create an external RPC IP Address, as it seems.

A quick solution to this issue of `truffle deploy` not working, was simply running a mobile hotspot from my Smart phone and connecting my host machine to the wifi. Then running `truffle deploy` without internet connection disabled from Smart phone got it working as expected, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

They released Truffle 4.0 just today which comes with a built-in replacement for testrpc.

After updating truffle and initializing it you can run $ truffle develop to get a development blockchain without testrpc. You could give it a try to check if it works offline. 
Here are the release notes:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases

Comment: Ok great, let me try the new release. be back here to update how it goes.

Comment: So, I updated to latest version of Truffle 4.0. And the problem seems to persist. `$ truffle develop
Truffle Develop started at http://localhost:9545/

Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)`

Comment: Works fine with internet connection, but does not work when disconnect and rerun using `truffle develop`. Currently using Windows 7 Pro SP1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your new contract is included in the "2_deploy_contracts.js" file like this.

var ContractFileName= artifacts.require("./contractfilename.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployer.deploy(ContractFileName);
};